# DMA issue, keyboard about to die?

Tags: linux, keyboard, debian, dma

I have this message when I boot up debian and it takes a bit before booting when it reaches this error message: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/762638/Files/Images/dma_issue.jpg

[image: DMA error]

If I mount the same o.s. on my laptop (I have it mounted on an USB drive), no error message and boot faster. Also, last reboot my keyboard didn't work until I shutted down computer (and turned it on again). Are these errors related to a keyboard? From what I've studied at university, DMA was related to keyboard, at least in past.

Comment: Do you get the DMA error if you boot without the KB plugged in?  Since you seem to be swapping the same OS between systems, have you got all the drivers installed for both sets of hardware?

Comment: I didn't test without keyboard but the o.s. was originally installed on the o.s. with the DMA issue, so at least all drivers for this system are installed (but yes, I've installed drivers for the other system too).

Comment: @techie007: I made a test without the keyboard and actually works without displaying the error. So I imagine is that. The strange part is that the keyboard keeps working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to say that my old answer is not correct.
I thought it was a motherboard issue but looks like it's not. My PCI-E SSD (OCZ Revodrive) is broken and in some way blocked my pc from turning on at all (a big damage I imagine).

I replaced it and the computer started again.

Meanwhile, for a completely different reason, I discovered what's causing the issue:
DRHD: handling fault status reg 2 and DMAR issues seems to be caused by **a bug in ASUS motherboard's bios** connected with **Intel VT-d** technology.

Disabling it, fixed the issue.